# How to Shrink Transaction log in sql server database in replication

Tags: sql-server

Hi I'm having a production database and its replicated report database. How to shrink the transaction log files in the production database as the log file size is increasing. I had tried  **DBCC SHRINKFILE** and **SHRINKDATABASE** commands but it does not work for me. I can't detach and shrink and attach back as the db in replication. Please help me in this issue.

Answer (score 17):

First check what is causing your database to not shrink by running:

```
SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.DATABASES
```

If you are blocked by a transaction, find which one with:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

Kill the transaction and shrink your db.

If the cause of the blocking is 'REPLICATION' and you are sure that your replicas are in sync, you might need to reset the status of replicated transactions. To see the status of what the database still think needs to be replicated use:

```
DBCC loginfo
```

You can reset this by first turning the Reader agent off (I usually just turn the whole SQL Server Agent off), and then run that query on the database for which you want to fix the replication issue:

```
EXEC sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_segno = NULL, @numtrans = 0, @time= 0, @reset = 1
```

Close the connection where you executed that query and restart SQL Server Agent (or just the Reader Agent). You should be all set to shrink your db now.

Comment: I had the SAME exact problem and this fixed the issue. Log file was over 90GB after doing a reinit. Do you know how it can get into these states?

Comment: Fixed my problem. My Log file was over 180GB and had filled up the drive it was on causing our application to fail. Everything I tried told me that either my log file was locked by REPLICATION or that my TLog file was filled. I stopped my whole SQL Server Agent, ran the EXEC you gave us above, I then was able to shrink my TLOG, and lastly I started SQL Server agent back up. Everything running great now.

Comment: Fixed my issue, now my log file is tiny compared to what it was

Answer (score 1):

The database won't let you remove transaction data that isn't backed up. First you have to back up the transaction log, then you can shrink it.

Comment: That i tried,but didn't worked for me.The size is not yet decreased

Comment: If your DB is in full recovery mode you need to make sure you're doing a transaction log backup as well as a database backup.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a regular backup schedule in place?

If not, I suggest you read this excellent article: [8 Steps to better Transaction Log throughput](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/8-Steps-to-better-Transaction-Log-throughput.aspx)

Comment: no i'm not having backup schedule.I need to remove the trancation log

Comment: The reason you have a large transaction log is because you are not backing up your database regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Shrink the logfile with dbcc shrinkfile

Then truncate the log file using

> Backup databaseName with truncate_only

Then shrink the logfile again

Answer (score 0):

I used [Red-Gate's SQL Backup](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Backup/index-2.html) tool to take care of the backing up. Then I just use the management console to issue a shrink command on the log file (telling it to rearrange the pages before releasing unused space).

Works like a charm.